# Mocha before hook is not working with chai-http

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

This is my test code. I'm testing an API. The problem is the "after" hook is working and dropping database after the test ends. But the "before" hook is not working. what's the issue here? I tried but unable to find out the issue. I tried to run the before hook with only one dummy test like logging something in the console. Didn't work either.

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const { assert } = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
require('../resolvedir');
const User = require('models/User');
const server = require('bin/www');
const testData = require('./test_data');

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Empty User Collection before test', function () {
  it('should drop User Collection before test starts', function () {
    before(function (done) {
      User.collection.drop();
      done();
    });
  });
});


describe('Testing /registration end point', () => {
  it('should return a valid JWT token', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/register')
      .send({ name: testData.name, email: testData.email, password: testData.password })
      .end((err, res) => {
        assert.equal(res.status, 200, 'Http response code is 200');
        assert.exists(res.body.auth, 'Auth confirmation message exist');
        assert.isTrue(res.body.auth, 'Auth confirmation message is true');
        assert.exists(res.body.token, 'JWT token is neither null or undefined');
        assert.isString(res.body.token, 'JWT token is string');
        done();
      });
  });

  it('should fail registration', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/register')
      .send(testData)
      .end((err, res) => {
        assert.equal(res.status, 409, 'Http response code is 409');
        assert.isString(res.body.message);
        assert.equal(res.body.message, 'User Exist');
        done();
      });
  });
});

describe('Testing /login end point', function () {
  it('should get a valid JWT token on successful login', function (done) {
    chai.request(server)
      .post('/login')
      .send({ email: testData.email, password: testData.password })
      .end((err, res) => {
        assert.isString(res.body.token, 'JWT token is string');
        done();
      });
  });
});

describe('Empty User Collection after test', function () {
  it('should drop User Collection after test ends', function () {
    after(function (done) {
      User.collection.drop();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: i think what you are looking for it this https://mochajs.org/#root-level-hooks

Comment: It's unclear what exactly is not working. before is used only once, it isn't used in tests where chai-http is used. There are several problems with posted code, I addressed them.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose and MongoDB support promises. `chai-http` [supports promises](http://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/#dealing-with-the-response---promises) as well.

`before` should reside inside `describe` block, not inside `it`.
Mocha supports promises for asynchronous blocks, no `done` is necessary. But the tests use `done` and in inconsistent way. `before` is asynchronous, but `done()` is called synchronously. `done()` is called only on success in tests, when assertion fails this results in test timeout.

It should be:

```
describe('Empty User Collection before test', function () {
  before(function () {
    return User.collection.drop();
  });

  it('should drop User Collection before test starts', function () {
    ...
  });
});
```

And

```
  it('should get a valid JWT token on successful login', function () {
    return chai.request(server)
      .post('/login')
      .send({ email: testData.email, password: testData.password })
      .then((res) => {
        assert.isString(res.body.token, 'JWT token is string');
      });
  });
```

And etc.

If a database should be dropped in `Testing /registration end point` test suite, there should `before` that drops a database as well - or all tests can have parent `describe` with `before`:

```
describe('Suite', function () {
  before(function () {
    return User.collection.drop();
  });

  describe('Testing /registration end point', () => {...})

  describe('Testing /login end point', () => {...})
  ...
});
```

Comment: I tried your last solution. Created a parent describe block and called `before` afterward. But still no luck.